# Android - Changing the (String... path) from asynctask into a function that sits at a service

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to take the asynctask code and converting it to a function that will run at a service class.

The asynctask  code starts like that -

```
    public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
             protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

                 String outPut = null;

                 for (String sdPath : path) {
                     Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
                     ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     //rest of the code
```

Now I've tried to convert it a function - like that -

```
     private String httpUploader (String path){

     String outPut = null;

         for (String sdPath : path) {
         Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
         ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

With this code above, it shows me the *path* is in error, at the line -

```
 for (String sdPath : path)
```

And when standing on it - it says - "Can only iterate over an array or instance of java.lang..."

So I guess that the problem is because that in the asynctask  the do in the backround function gets - String... path.

So with what can I changed it in order to get this error off?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a for loop like that, the compiler expects an array (or another kind of type that you can iterate over) rather than just a string.

Change your method declaration so you pass an array instead

So this:

```
private String httpUploader (String path){
```

should be this

```
private String httpUploader (String[] paths){
```

Alternatively you could pass an ArrayList

Comment: Any by your example I understand that I've also need to change the path in the for line into paths, right?!?

Comment: @4this - No. The rest of your code should work fine if you pass an array. If you only want to use one path, then you should remove the ` for (String sdPath : path) ` instead